# Dhcp context is missing from windows xp netsh

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, dhcp, netsh

How can I add the dhcp context using netsh commands on Windows XP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh_dhcp.mspx?mfr=true

> You cannot run these [DHCP] Netsh commands locally on Windows XP Professional or Windows XP Home Edition.

edit: To clarify, you can still set an XP machine to use DHCP through netsh via:

> netsh interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” source=dhcp

edit edit: from http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/80459/jsi-tip-7839-when-you-type-netsh-dhcp--in-windows-xp-you-receive-the-following-command-was-not-found-dhcp-.html

> > NETSH SHOW HELPER
>
> If DHCP is not displayed, add the DHCP
>   context:
>
> NETSH ADD HELPER DHCPMON.DLL